# `Error: attempt to use zero-length variable name` in R Code that works on other computer

Tags: r, r-markdown

My friend wrote a .Rmd file which I am running in R studio. It works on their machine. The first chunk is :

````
```{r packages, include = F}
rm(list = ls()) # clear all the data from your environment
library(tidyverse) # data manipulation
library(ggplot2) # visualization 
library(randomForest) # random forests
library(pROC) # for ROC and AUC
library(caret) # for accuracy and confusion matrix
set.seed(42)
```
````

When i try and run the chunk the first line ```{r packages, include = F} produces
`Error: attempt to use zero-length variable name`

I can't see where this could be coming from as the code worked for my friend apparently.

Comment: What happens if you run that code *one line at a time* in the console?

Answer (score 2):

That's a snippet of code from a R Markdown.

You can't just copy-paste it in an R script. R script (.R) and R Markdown (.Rmd) are two different kind of files.

If you use an R Script, just copy-paste the lines from rm(list = ls()) to set.seed(42) and it will work fine.

If you use an R Markdown the first and the last line are just there to communicate that the lines in the middle are R code and they should be evaluated as R code.

Specifically, the first line tells the program that the chunk of code is an R code that you decided to call "packages" and that, although it needs be evaluate, its output shouldn't be included in the final file (that you get when you knit the file. Knitting the file = creating a pdf or html out of it by clicking on KNIT).

Comment: Thanks for responding. It's still in a .Rmd file, i haven't copy pasted it into an R-script i am just trying to run the chunk.